# update statement with inner join

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to update a table with records from another table in access. The update statement i am using is as folows;

```
UPDATE Laptop_tracker
INNER JOIN Assets_L ON Laptop_tracker.serialno = Assets_L.serialno
SET Laptop_tracker.hklcode = [Assets_L]![hklcode], 
Laptop_tracker.make = [Assets_L]![make],
Laptop_tracker.model = [Assets_L]![model],
Laptop_tracker.[user] = [Assets_L]![User], 
Laptop_tracker.principal = [Assets_L]![principal] 
WHERE Laptop_tracker.serialno = Assets_L.serialno;
```

It isn't working. How can i solve this?

Comment: Please tag your dbms.

Comment: Which dbms (database management system) is that?

Comment: The `WHERE` is superfluous

Comment: Explain what `not working` means.  It is not obvious.

Comment: The records are not being updated @GordonLinoff

Comment: ms access @Jonast92

Comment: The code appears to work (Access 2010)  - you can remove the `WHERE` clause though as @JohnHC said.  Does it give any messages when you run it?  It should just say "You are about to update x row(s)".  Could we have a sample of data please?

Comment: It wirked after i removed the where clause. @DarrenBartrup-Cook